# Error:Whatever his intention may be he should consider them carefully before he comes to a decision

Tags: exam-questions

> Whatever his intention may be he should consider them carefully before he comes to a decision.

Is the above sentence correct ?

I am doubtful for the usage of *them* with *intention* since *intention* is singular don't I need to use *it* in place of *them* or replace *intention* with *intention**s*** ?

Comment: What is the source of this sentence?  What is the context?  It is likely that "them" refers to something mentioned earlier in the passage, such as options from which he might choose or people who might be affected by his decision.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Standalone sentence from an error spotting exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the pronoun (*them*) does not match the noun it refers to (*intention*).  You should either make the pronoun singular (*it*) or the noun plural (*intentions*).